# SQL query tune up while fetching data for counting the records by joining 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I am having problem in fetching a number of records from while joining tables. Please see the below query:

```
SELECT 
  H.EIN, 
  H.OUC, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(1) 
    FROM 
      tbl_Checks C 
    INNER JOIN INFM_People_OR.dbo.tblHierarchy P 
      ON P.EIN = C.EIN_Checked 
    WHERE 
      (H.EIN IN (P.L1, P.L2) 
      OR H.EIN = C.EIN_Checked) 
      AND C.[Read] = 1 
  ) AS [Read] 
FROM 
  INFM_People_OR.dbo.tblHierarchy H 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_Checks C 
    ON H.EIN = C.EIN_Checked 
WHERE 
  H.L1 = @EIN 
GROUP BY 
    H.EIN, 
    H.OUC,
    C.Check_Date
```

Even if there are just 100 records this query takes a much more time(around 1 min).

Please suggest a solution to tune up this query as it is throwing error in front end

Comment: You should post some sample data using sqlfiddle.com and also explain what you are trying to do so we can eval the query to see if there is a less complicated way of doing it.

Comment: When you look at the execution plan, what part is taking the longest?

Comment: The below code snippet takes the longest time:
WHERE 
      (H.EIN IN (P.L1, P.L2) 
     ** OR H.EIN = C.EIN_Checked) **

The bold part is specially taking a longer time to execute and if I remove this part it executes relatively fast but will not give the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Given just the query there are a few things that stick out as being non-optimal:

Any use of OR will be slower:

```
WHERE 
  (H.EIN IN (P.L1, P.L2) 
  OR H.EIN = C.EIN_Checked) 
  AND C.[Read] = 1
```

If there's any way to rework this based off of your data set so that both the IN and the OR are replaced with ANDs that would help.

Also, use of a local variable in the WHERE clause will not work well with the optimizer:

```
WHERE 
  H.L1 = @EIN
```

Finally, make sure you have indexes (and hopefully these are integer fields) where you are doing your joins and group bys (H.EIN, H.OUC, C.Check_Date

The size of the result set (100 records) doesn't matter as much as the size of the joined tables and whether or not they have appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The Estimated number of rows affected is 1196880  is very high resulting in high execution time of query. I have also tried to join the tables only once but that it giving different output.

Please suggest any other solution than creating indices as I have already created non-clustered index for the table tbl_checks but it doesn't make any difference.

Below is the SQl execution plan.

[image]